# Amazon S3 and M3u8 and ts files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i encode my videos to Hls locally
then
i upload them to the s3 bucket in aws and disable public access
then
i made IAM user with this primission

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

then added only permission to access bucket from my domain

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.mydomain.ext/*",
                        "http://mydomain.ext/*",
                        "https://www.mydomain.ext/*",
                        "https://mydomain.ext/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

then enabled cors

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

now i use wordpress on my domain and installed fv player and added the key and the secret

the problem is :

when i try to play mp4 , it work fine
when i try to play the  .m3u8 file not work, it loads the m3u8 file but give 403 error when it loads ts file

when i make the bucket public it work fine

how i make it private and solve the 403 error , knowing that all the credentials are correct and work when connect to mp4 file just fine

in the attached image the 1st xhr request is successful and it's for the m3u8 file
the below xhr requests is for the ts file and all are 403 error
[image]
any help in this ?

Answer (score 0):

i think i have to uncheck this option

- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public or access point policies

i don't know if there's some roles to enable private access without unchecking this option, but at my end it just work.